# Android remove border hover from FloatActionbutton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, floating-action-button

[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4EXU.png)

So as you can see on the picture there is a shadow on the border of my button. Is there a way to remove the shadow so that that the color of the button corresponds with the color of my action bar. right know it looks ugly because you can see the shadow. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<TableRow
    android:gravity="end">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/logInButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/faviconColor"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: background="@null"

Comment: @ivan nop doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `android:elevation="0dp"` to your floatingaction button.

Nevertheless, why even use a FloatingActionButton, and not just a normal button? FloatingActionButtons are afaik not made to be used like this, and if you need e.g. a round ripple effect, there are more elegant ways to do this.

EDIT: 
If this does not work (as sometimes) use `app:elevation="0dp"` instead

Comment: @jenej Depending on your API version you could also try `app:elevation="0dp"` for this. But as I said, why even use a Fab? Normal buttons will do the exact same thing in your case.

Comment: thanks app:elevation solved the problem? Whats so bad about ussing floatingactionbuttons?

Comment: @jenej [Material Design Dokumentation](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#usage) A Floatingactionbutton is designed to be the primary action, and floating over your content (as the name). You are forcefully changing the appearance and purpose of the fab, instead of using a normal button in this case. For a drawable, use a ImageButton instead, with selectableItemBackground as background for the ripple effect. You want have the problems with shadows like with the fab. If my answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I am not specialized in designing apps so i dont know what good and bad practise. Could any problems occure if I still deside using floationactionbutton?

Comment: The only attribute to use is `app:elevation`. You can check the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md#attributes).

Comment: You are right, whyever android:elevation also worked for me. You are, however, correct that app:elevation is the correct one to use.